# Accessing put variables using the SLIM framework

Tags: php, rest, slim

I am using the `Slim framework` to develop my rest `API`. I am having problems with the `PUT` request. I want to access variables sent from the client on the server side.

```
$app->put('post/:pid', function ($pid) {
    //how to access other data sent from the client?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer the code below:

```
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
$request = $app->request();
$var = $request->put();
```

The variable is the form of array at $var

Comment: Just seeing your response! I had gotten this to work before $request = $app->request(); $_PUT = $request->params(); Thanks for your reply..